# OMNeT++,in Tictoc example code,how does .cc file connect to .ned file

Tags: omnet++

I'm now looking at the tictoc example code to understand how OMNeT++ works,and I am confused about how does the .cc file control the message that is send in the simulation.In .ned file,it doesn't include .cc file,so how does this two file get connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple modules are atomic on NED level. They are active components, and their behavior is implemented in C++.

Therefore, the file `tictoc1.ned` describes the module itself and the `tictoc1.cc` describes the behavior. 
The TicToc1 module has two gates named `in` and `out` which are declared as input and output gates. The handling or usage of those gates is implemented in C++. If we have a look to the according [file](https://docs.omnetpp.org/showfile/?url=tutorials/tictoc/code/txc1.cc) line 42 and 43 shows an example:

```
cMessage *msg = new cMessage("tictocMsg");
send(msg, "out");
```

A standard cMessage gets created and scheduled for the `out` gate.

The TicToc module can be used in a network afterwards to get connected to other nodes. If you have a look to the according [file](https://docs.omnetpp.org/showfile/?url=tutorials/tictoc/code/tictoc1.ned) line 28,29 and 30 show how the gates of the modules are connected to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The statement of `"Define_Module(simplemodule_name)"` bind the module in Ned file with function in cc file.
Maybe you can test it by changing the `simplemodule_name`.